# Rails nested models error translation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, internationalization, rails-i18n

I have problem translating error messages for nested models.

Lets say we have a parent class `Foo` which accepts attributes for `Bar`:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bars

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bars
  validates_associated :bars
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo

  validates :a, presence: true
end
```

If I create a `Foo` with an invalid `Bar`, it validates `bars` (notice the plural name `bars` in the error messages):

```
foo = Foo.new(bars_attributes: [b: 'something'])
foo.valid?
foo.errors.messages
=> {:"bars.a"=>["must be present"] }
```

When this is translated, `I18n` seems to be looking for the translations for the association name (`bars` in plural) instead of the singular model name (`bar`) in the translation file (the Swedish one for instance) `config/local/sv`:

```
sv:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      bar:
        a: 'The normal place for the translation'
      bars:
        a: 'The place where I18n is using when nested with Foo'
```

Obviously I do not want to state my translations twice, I want to get rid of the two last lines in the config.

Why is `I18n` using the association name when looking for translation for the nested model? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure the usage of association name can be helped. But i can offer you a partial solution:

```
sv:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      bar: &bar
        a: 'The normal place for the translation'
      bars: *bar
```

EDIT: The `&identifier` sets up the anchor referencing the preceding hash, while `*identifier` allows you to reference that anchor. In this scenario, the "*bar" reference will take the "bar" underlying structure and include it into "bars".

Take a look at this quick guide: http://rhnh.net/2011/01/31/yaml-tutorial
Of course, you're also welcome to try the elaborate YAML docs or this wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML

Comment: Well, this looks promising! Just curious, can you explain how the `&bar` and `*bar` works? And where did you find this (is there any documentation or similar)? I have been looking...

Comment: Great! I'll try this out and mark as solved if it works :)